# C# with mdb dataTabel.LoadDataRow too slow

Tags: c#, performance, ms-access, datarow

The problem is with C# from Visual Studio 2005 and Microsoft Access 2003 mdb file.
The fallowing code is extremly slow when I have a lot of records (around 500k)

```
foreach (DataRow parentrow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
childrows = parentrow.GetChildRows(r);
if (childrows == null || childrows.Length == 0)
{
      table.LoadDataRow(parentrow.ItemArray, true);
}
}
```

Any solution to speed up the code?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
table = ds.Tables[0];
```

Edgar